# Using a body as a silencer?

Tags: firearms

So I was shooting the other day and my friends were talking about how effective silencers are and since I was writing a short detective story I wondered how effective a human would be as a silencer. The pistol in question is a .38 police special firing from point blank into the suspects stomachs. The person is wearing limited clothing but if it is too loud can a heavy coat help? How much noise will this make?

Comment: It will make basically as much noise as normal shooting. Gases will escape from the cylinder and the barrel as they will push the victim away. Therefore noise. How the victim is clothed wont make any significant difference.

Comment: This is a question about exploring real-world physics for use in a story. There is no worldbuilding context here.

Answer (score 4):

First, it's a "suppressor", not a "silencer".  If you've ever heard a suppressed firearm fired, you'll know they're still pretty loud -- just not "gunshot" loud.

Second, suppressing a revolver is mostly an exercise in futility.  The only revolver ever made that supresses well is the Nagant with its gas seal cartridge (nests into the rear of the barrel by moving the cylinder forward for each shot).  They went out of production more than a century ago for good reasons.

Third, a body isn't likely to be a very effective suppressor.  To suppress the report from a firearm, you need something that acts like a muffler, trapping the gas from behind the bullet and releasing it gradually.  A pillow works in the movies; a large beverage bottle also, but neither is very effective in the real world.  Perhaps better than nothing, perhaps not.  A body isn't even as good as a pillow; all you'd do is blow fragments of the body back at the shooter from the gas blown into the entry wound, but you wouldn't delay or spread out the discharge enough to have much suppression effect.  Give the victim a heavy overcoat and you're up to about pillow level -- which isn't much.

Last: this is potentially dangerous (aside from the "body donor" getting a bullet shot through them).  A body can act as a barrel obstruction, potentially leading to a bullet lodging in the bore.  If this occurs, and another bullet is fired without noticing and clearing the bore, the gun will be damaged -- potentially to the point of explosive failure, which can injure (or, in extreme cases, even kill) the shooter.  This isn't a high probability with .38 Special police loads, because they're relatively high power, but if the revolver were loaded with, say, target wadcutters, there's a distinct risk here.

TL;DR -- it won't work, and could be hazardous to the shooter (and the person supplying the body won't like it, either).  Also, since you can't aim (there's a body blocking the sights) you're unlikely to get an accurate enough hit to make the loss of bullet velocity (from shooting through a body) a good trade off.

Comment: A pillow would make an absolutely terrible suppressor. They aren't airtight and so the gases just blow right through them completely uncontained. The main reason you see them used at all is to prevent blood splatter. 

A soda bottle has no baffles, and so it does very little to lower the noise as well. The shockwave is coupled directly to the bottle, which transfers it quite well to the air.

Comment: "First, it's a "suppressor", not a "silencer"." The OP is asking about silencers, not suppressors. These two things are NOT the same thing.

Comment: @PcMan In that one exists and the other doesn't, you're correct, but "silencer" in connection with guns is, in my experience, *always* a misnomer for a suppressor.  There are suppressors (for .22 rimfire) that reduce the report to the point you can clearly hear the firing pin fall -- but "suppressor" is still the correct term.